# How to stop event bubbling for mouseover/mouseout events in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

So I've been banging my head against the table over this task...
I have a navbar that looks like this:

```
<nav class="headerNavbar" id="headerNavbarPertinent">
            ...
            <div class="navbarElement" data-forCyclicAssignment="resources">
                <span>Resources</span><div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
</nav>
```

It has a certain amount of such divs that represent parts of the navbar.
There is JavaScript that adds event listeners to the divs that are named 'navbarElement':

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(navbarElements,function(node){
    if (Number(node.getAttribute('data-bypassCyclicAssignment'))!==1) {
        node.addEventListener('mouseover',mouseOverHandler)
        node.addEventListener('mouseout',mouseOutHandler)
    } 
});
```

However, in Internet Explorer 10, NOT EVERY TIME, but maybe every 4 or 5 times, the event.target is not the the element but the parent (NAV element). I was trying to use both stopPropagation() and setting cancelBubble to true to stop upward propagation with no luck. What could be happening?

Comment: Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. Why are you doing `Array.prototype.forEach` anyways?

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I'm doing it to convert the html collection to a regular array

Comment: @StackSlave That's the old idiom for `Array.from(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: @OlegArsyonov Events `mouseenter/mouseleave` do not bubble. From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You could put the solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.